# Returning an array from DB query as JSON and then putting the contents into list elements with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, laravel

I have a commenting system I am working on thats is aiming to be like instagrams system.

Currently, I show the last 3 items in a PHP foreach and also have a 'show all button'.

My aim is then that button gets clicked and calls a function which then returns all the comments as an array. I then would need to .prepend() this array as list elements.

Normally an AJAX call to fetch data is fine. But in the past I have only retuned one line values.

I am using Laravel so my function to fetch would be something like:

```
public function fetch() {
  DB:: // SELECT ALL COMMENTS
  $commentsArray = array();
  foreach ($comments as $comment) {
     $commentsArray = (array('commentusername', 'comment'));
  }

  return Response::json(array(
    'success' => true,
    'comments' => $commentsArray,
  200)
  );
}
```

And then in my jQuery call:

```
if (data.success) {
  $(".comments_"+id).prepend("<li><b>USERNAME:</b> Comment</li>");
}
```

That prepend woulds as I want, but I need to learn how I should be correctly creating the array, and then how I can loop through them and create the list elements in jQuery.

Note, that PHP function is written here and untested etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get an array of the format you want:

```
public function fetch() {
    DB:: // SELECT ALL COMMENTS
    $commentsArray = array_map(function($comment){
        return array(
                'username' => $comment->commentusername,
                'comment' => $comment->comment
        );
    }, $comments);

    return Response::json(array(
        'success' => true,
        'comments' => $commentsArray
    ));
}
```

(I changed commentusername to username for the output array. Also you don't need the `200` in your response)

Now this is what your response will look like:

```
{
    success: true,
    comments: [
        {username: 'foo', comment: 'comment of foo'},
        {username: 'foo', comment: 'comment of foo'}
    ]
}
```

Then in your javascript code, do this:

```
if (data.success) {
    for(var i=0; i<data.comments.length; i++){
        var comment = data.comments[i];
        $(".comments_"+id).prepend("<li><b>"+comment.username+":</b> "+comment.comment+"</li>");
    }
}
```

Also note that if you use HTTP status codes for errors, you can remove `success: true` and assume that if the response is 200 (ajax success callback) the request has been made successfully.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Lots of extra information in there too. Also works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your question, but  i m gonna to show you, how you can get json response from script and then can parse that,

```
// script.php

<?php

   $data = array(

        array('User' : 'Tiger', 'Comment' : 'Any comment,, '),
        array('User' : 'John', 'Comment' : 'Tiger is nice guy !!') 

   );  // In reality data will fetch from Db 

   header('Content-Type: application/json');  // must be set, and no space between ...pe and ':'
   echo json_encode($data);   

?>
```

client_side.js

```
 $.get('script.php', function(data) {

         for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

                $(".comments_"+id).prepend("<li><b>USERNAME :</b> " + data[i].User + " <b> Comment :</b> " + data[i].Comment  + "</li>");  // You should use templete here

         } // __prepending comments

 }, 'json');
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You also have to send other request permeters with this ajax request :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add your arrays to an array. As you do, you are always just overwrite your variable:

```
$commentsArray[] = (array('commentusername', 'comment'));
```

add a `[]` after your name of variable.

And then in the jQuery:

```
$.each(data, function(idx, obj) {
    $(".comments_"+id).prepend("<li><b>USERNAME:" + obj.commentusername + ", </b> Comment</li>" + obj.comment);
});
```

NOTE: Don't forget to check and change your `id` in the loop.

Comment: My array in that case would be set as `$commentsArray[] = (array($username, $comment));` In this case, how do I then get the values in jQuery? [0] / [1] ?

Comment: `data.commentusername`, `data.comment`. See my loop.